# blazor run in docker,How to get client IP？

Tags: docker, blazor

```
 string loginip = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();// not get
 string loginip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();// not get,only get docker ip
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track where you're using the X-Forwarded-For.
It's the responsibility of the process that's forwarding the HTTP Request to the container to add the value(s) to that header.
This normally involves using a reverse proxy such as nginx.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/